# how can i change the date format in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, discord, discord.js

I am coding a discord bot and I want to add created at and joined to user info. I added them but the date was different. The date was like Fri Mar 10 2017 23:14:16 this but I wanted to do it MM/DD/YYYY format. I couldn't find any solution so I am here.

The first image is the result of the code I wrote but I want it to be like in the second image.

First Image:

[image]

Second Image:

[image]

Comment: You should show  us what you have tried already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `npm` package [`moment`](https://npmjs.com/package/moment)

```js
// example of a format, although you can use whichever your want
moment(user.createdAt).format('M/D/YYYY');
moment(member.joinedAt).format('M/D/YYYY');
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDTss.png]